# D3js reverse number order on spider/radar chart, from bigger to smaller number

Tags: d3.js, charts, axis

I am creating a spider chart using this code: http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614. In the chart I need to create, I need to reverse the order of the numbers such as 100% is actually the point in the middle and 0% is the point at the exterior. Please see this screenshot to understand better what I am trying to do: [what I wish to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qcfk.png). The biggest number (7) is in the middle of the graph whereas the smaller number (1) is at the end of the graph.

I saw online that I can reverse the range of the scale. I tried this but it did not work. I am not sure where to go from here.

I am new to D3 and any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the example that you've mentioned. I made a few changes to it's code (`Radarchart.js` is the file that you need to tweak). However, this change will only reverse the values of text in `%` format (just like you asked). Let me warn you though, changing the default display order will result in wrong interpretation of data. So make sure, you change the affected areas too. I have created a pen for you so that you can tweak around until you get the desired result. Here is the code that has changed so that you know :)

**Radarchart.js**

```
//Text indicating at what % each level is
    var t = [];
    for (var j = (cfg.levels - 1);
      (j < cfg.levels && j >= 0); j--) {
      t.push(cfg.factor * radius * ((j + 1) / cfg.levels))
    }

    for (var j = (cfg.levels - 1);
      (j < cfg.levels && j >= 0); j--) {
      var levelFactor = t[j];

      g.selectAll(".levels")
        .data([1]) //dummy data
        .enter()
        .append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.sin(0));
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return levelFactor * (1 - cfg.factor * Math.cos(0));
        })
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (cfg.w / 2 - levelFactor + cfg.ToRight) + ", " + (cfg.h / 2 - levelFactor) + ")")
        .attr("fill", "#737373")
        .text(Format((j + 1) * cfg.maxValue / cfg.levels));
    }
```

Link to the pen: [Radar chart](http://codepen.io/thomsebastin/pen/jqrrjj?editors=0010)